# In unix how to find out if process running and return true/false?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm writing a unix shell script and need to check if there are currently running processes with "xyz" in their directory. If yes than continue to next command and show text like "Found It".

If not than don't continue and display text like "Process Not Found".

I tried something like this:

```
if ps -ef | grep xyz
then
    echo "XYZ Process Found!"
else
    echo "XYZ Process Not Found!"
fi
```

But it just showing me the processes and display "process found" even if there's no xyz process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want to check the output of the command against a value using [Command substition](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst), from the linked bash-hackers wiki *The command substitution expands to the output of commands. These commands are executed in a subshell, and their stdout data is what the substitution syntax expands to.* Also, count the lines and remove grep. Something like,

```
if [[ $(ps -ef | grep xyz | grep -v grep | wc -l) != 0 ]]; then
        echo "XYZ Process Found!"
else
        echo "XYZ Process Not Found!"
fi
```

**Edit**

Based on the comments below, you should probably use

```
if [[ $(ps -ef | grep -c xyz)  -ne 1 ]]; then
```

which is a lot easier to read.

Comment: this works only that i changed the !=0 to !=1 because on ps -ef it return a single header for each set of process even if there aren't any matches.

Comment: @user1508682 I tested it here first, and I get "Process Found" when I use != 1. `ps --version` outputs *procps-ng version 3.3.9* here. Do you have the same?

Comment: too much of UUO*.. http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#wc  `if ps -ef | grep -q [x]yz; then ... else ... fi` should work..

Comment: @anishsane Nice link. And you're right, it suggested several alternatives. I liked the `-c` which I've tested here as well.

Comment: `psgrep` is a thing on some systems.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `grep xyz`, that process - `grep xyz` - is also running & thus shown in the output of `ps -ef`.
This running process command line contains `xyz`. Thus grep passes that line to output.
Hence you always get zero exit status - i.e. success.

2 Solutions:

1. use `if ps -ef | grep '[x]yz'; then`. (You may want to suppress `grep` output with `-q`)
   The grep command being run is `grep [x]yz`. This gets printed in `ps -ef` output.
   Obviously, grep filters out this line. `[x]yz` could be matched with `\[x\]yz`, not with `[x]yz`.
2. use `if pgrep -f xyz >/dev/null; then`
   Check [`man pgrep`](http://man.cx/pgrep) for more details..

Comment: `pgrep` is usually what people prefer. But I like `grep [x]yz` version more. If you don't want to suppress the output, you can get the command line on the screen. Else you need to use `ps -f $(pgrep -f xyz)` for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `pgrep`. From `pgrep(1)`:

> pgrep looks through the  currently  running  processes  and  lists  the
>   process IDs which match the selection criteria to stdout.
>
> [...]
>
> EXIT STATUS
>    0      One or more processes matched the criteria.
>    1      No processes matched.
>    2      Syntax error in the command line.
>    3      Fatal error: out of memory etc.

Example output:

```
[~]% pgrep xterm
18231
19070
31727
```

You can use it in an `if` statement like so:

```
if pgrep xterm > /dev/null; then
  echo Found xterm
else
  echo xterm not found
fi
```

Note: `pgrep` is not a standard utility (ie. it's not in POSIX), but widely available on at least Linux and I believe most BSD systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
is_xyz_running() {
  [ "$(pgrep xyz)" ] && echo true || echo false
}
```